# custom sql : add multilist in filter

Tags: sql, business-objects

i'm working with webi (sap business object), i use custom sql to add filter, I want to display a list based on the CDS field and the user selects the values he wants, but i don't know how to point my @prompt on the CDS fields this my code

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN ID LIKE ('T%') THEN 'TERMINAL'
  WHEN ID LIKE ('S%') THEN 'SIM'
  WHEN ID LIKE ('R%') THEN 'RECHARGE'
  WHEN ID LIKE ('N%') THEN 'NUMBER_PHONE'
ELSE  'UKNOWN' END  AS TYPEE,
A.* FROM 
 P_STG_POSA.inventory A
WHERE    ID LIKE ('R%')
AND OUTDATE BETWEEN @Prompt('Date vente From','D',,,) AND @Prompt('Date vente To','D',,,)
and 
CDS in @prompt('CDS:','A',[{'inventory/CDS'}],[MULTI],[FREE] )
```